# Symphony3 database creation error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to use symphony for the first time to create a database.
I have this 2 file `Film.php` contained in the directory `MovieManagerBundle\Entity` and `Film.orm.yml` contained in `MovieManagerBundle\Resources\config\doctrine`.
When I use the command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`
I have this error:

> [RuntimeException]
>    The autoloader expected class "MovieManagerBundle\Entity\Film" to be defined in file "C:\xampp\php\FilmManager\vendor\composer/../../src/MovieManagerBundle\Entity\Film.php".

The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

I dont understand what is the error, this is my code:

Film.php

```
<?php

namespace MovieManagerBundle\Entity;


class Movie
{

  private $id;
  private $title;
  private $director;
  private $year;


  public function __construct($title,$director,$year){
    $this->setTitle($title);
    $this->setDirector($director);
    $this->setYear($year);
  }

  public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function getTitle(){
    return $this->title;
  }

  public function setTitle($title){
    $this->title = $title;
  }

  public function getDirector(){
    return $this->director;
  }

  public function setDirector($director){
    $this->director = $director;
  }

  public function getYear(){
    return $this->year;
  }

  public function setYear($year){
    $this->year = $year;
  }
}


 ?>
```

Film.orm.yml

```
MovieManagerBundle\Entity\Film:
  type: entity
  table: movie
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    title:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: false
      column: title
    director:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: false
      column: director
    year:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
      column: year
```

Comment: Try changing class Movie by Class Film.. Regards

Answer (score 2):

You have to change name `Movie` to `Film`. Because `autoloader` find your class `MovieManagerBundle\Entity\Film` but in `class` you named class name `class Movie`.

```
class Movie
```

To

```
class Film
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem I hope that It was an error of copy because this:

```
<<?phpnamespace MovieManagerBundle\Entity;
```

should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace MovieManagerBundle\Entity;
```

Second problem change the name `Movie` to `Film`

If isn't a problem of copy and paste or a name problem I think It's a problem of composer try to open your `composer.json` because your application search the entity inside vendor directory not inside your bundle, so I suppose that your bundle isn't loaded.
Open your `composer.json`  file and edit the `autoload` section into this:

```
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
```

After launch this from your console:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Clean the cache and retry please

Comment: change the name Movie to Film please @AntonioSparacio

Comment: I think is that..regards

Comment: dont work. I have my bundle in this directory C:\xampp\php\FilmManager\src\MovieManagerBundle

Comment: I have modified the composer.json file in FilmManager

Comment: Have you launched composer dump-autoload ?

Answer (score 0):

**Advise**

> i think for better structure is to use *yml* for routing and annotation for
>   entities especially when you have large entities